# How to set a value preference in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The following code is from a sample project about Kotlin, I can use Code 1 to get a value of a shared preferences, but I can  set a value of a shared preferences?

I can't find those code in the sample project, could you tell me how I can do? Thanks!

**Code 1**

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        val ZIP_CODE = "zipCode"
        val DEFAULT_ZIP = 94043L
    }

    var zipCode: Long by DelegatesExt.preference(this, ZIP_CODE, DEFAULT_ZIP)
}
```

**Code 2**

```
object DelegatesExt {
    fun <T> notNullSingleValue() = NotNullSingleValueVar<T>()
    fun <T> preference(context: Context, name: String, default: T) = Preference(context, name, default)
}

class NotNullSingleValueVar<T> {

    private var value: T? = null

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return value ?: throw IllegalStateException("${property.name} not initialized")
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        this.value = if (this.value == null) value
        else throw IllegalStateException("${property.name} already initialized")
    }
}

class Preference<T>(val context: Context, val name: String, val default: T) {

    val prefs: SharedPreferences by lazy { context.getSharedPreferences("default", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) }

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return findPreference(name, default)
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        putPreference(name, value)
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    private fun findPreference(name: String, default: T): T = with(prefs) {
        val res: Any = when (default) {
            is Long -> getLong(name, default)
            is String -> getString(name, default)
            is Int -> getInt(name, default)
            is Boolean -> getBoolean(name, default)
            is Float -> getFloat(name, default)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can be saved into Preferences")
        }

        res as T
    }

    private fun putPreference(name: String, value: T) = with(prefs.edit()) {
        when (value) {
            is Long -> putLong(name, value)
            is String -> putString(name, value)
            is Int -> putInt(name, value)
            is Boolean -> putBoolean(name, value)
            is Float -> putFloat(name, value)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can't be saved into Preferences")
        }.apply()
    }
}
```

**And More**

If the function putPreference is public, I can set value of a shared preferences using the code below, but it's ugly

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        val ZIP_CODE = "zipCode"
        val DEFAULT_ZIP = 94043L
    }

   DelegatesExt.Preference(this, ZIP_CODE, DEFAULT_ZIP).putPreference( ZIP_CODE,"99999L");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what `operator fun setValue` is for: you just write

```
activity.zipCode = 1L
```

(where `activity` is a `SettingsActivity`) or

```
zipCode = 1L
```

(inside `SettingsActivity` or a class extending it) and it'll call `setValue(activity, activity::zipCode, 1L)` which calls `putPreference("zipCode", 1L)`. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html for more.

Comment: Thanks! Could you write a full code to set  a value of a shared preferences?    I can't understand why `activity.zipCode="MyNewZIP" ` will `invoke setValue(activity, "zipCode", ...)`

Comment: Because that's how delegated properties are defined to work. Have you read the link?

Comment: You can't use `"MyNewZIP"` because the type is `Long` (which doesn't really make sense for zip code).

Comment: I've got the second argument of `setValue` wrong, edited the answer.